# Ratio instead of existing values

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am trying to find the ratio for two values in a visualization.
How many "light blue values" for every "dark blue values".
I would like the visualization only to show a stacked column with this info.
e.g 1.2 as a ratio.

How tried performing a quick measure with a division but this is not working?

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far, the table structure and the DAX you used so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data, the best way to answer this would be this 3 measures:

```
Sum First Value = Sum([YourTable]'Value1')
Sum Second Value = Sum([YourTable]'Value2')

Ratio First/Second = [Sum First Value] / [Sum Second Value]
```